# How to save an array of dates read from mysql on php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to save save the data as an array for the next year, $info is read from sql:

```
$saved = []
for ($x = 0; $x <= 365; $x++) {
    $d=strtotime("+$x days");
    $cd = date("Y-m-d", $d);
    foreach($info as $i){
        if($i['date'] == $cd){  
            $saved[$cd] = $i;
        }
    }
}
```

it works, but when I have many data with the same date it overrides it, how can I differentiate it without ruining the structure of

Comment: You need another dimension....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$saved = []
for ($x = 0; $x <= 365; $x++) {
    $d=strtotime("+$x days");
    $cd = date("Y-m-d", $d);
    foreach($info as $i){
        if($i['date'] == $cd){  
            $saved[$cd][] = $i;
        }
    }
}
```

that way $saved[$cd] is being pushed. That way $saved['2016-10-03'] will give you 1 result if there is only one, or an array of N if there are N results.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$saved = array();
$dates = array();
// separate array, make array for dates
for ($x = 0; $x <= 365; $x++) {
  $d=strtotime("+$x days");
  $cd = date("Y-m-d", $d);
  $dates[$cd] = $cd;
}

foreach($info as $i){
  if(isset($dates[$i['date'])) {
        $saved[$i['date']][] = $i;
    }
}
```